# Mongodb string datatype is too large

Tags: string, mongodb, mongoose, size, string-length

I want to write a paragraph (string) in mongo-db database, but due to string size limit I cannot write a complete paragraph. How can I increase the limit of the string datatype?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [BSON spec])(http://bsonspec.org/spec.html) the string type is limited to 32bit length, which far exceeds the maximum size of a BSON object.

There are other limits, such as the [Index Key Limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/index.html#Index-Key-Limit), [BSON Document Size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/index.html#BSON-Document-Size) that may be coming into play here.

If the field you are putting the string in has been indexed, the size will be limited to 1024 bytes, or possibly less if the index includes other fields.

In a quick test using the mongo shell, I was able to insert a string 30 bytes less than the 16MB limit (to allow space for the _id and object overhead):

```
> db.test.insert({s:"A".repeat(Math.pow(2,20)*16-30)})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> var obj=db.test.findOne()
> bsonsize(obj)
16777216
> obj.s.length
16777186
```

Comment: can you please explain more ? @joe

Comment: The database already allows string datatype over 15MB in size, so that is probably not the limit you are encountering.